# What's the meaning of "十力所"

Tags: kanji, counters

I'm currently reading 極主夫道 and I'm not sure I understand "十力所". Do you have any ideas? Is it 10 powerful people of the office or something else? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if we point out that it's not 力 (the kanji that means power), but a small ヵ that would help you find the relevant entry in the dictionary.

Comment: What @Leebo said.  Or try looking up either of these:  十ヶ所 or 十箇所.

Comment: Got it, I had the answer I was looking for, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

箇所(カ所、ヶ所) means a place, a spot, a point, a part.

抗争相手の事務所を十カ所潰した means "The yakuza made ten enemy (Japanese mafia) offices close", "The yakuza destroyed ten enemy (Japanese mafia) offices".

Comment: But I think in this case it's not the man himself speaking about this.

Comment: Yes, it is narration.